# Can't add new rows to Postgres database at Heroku via Django admin

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

After provisioning my Postgres database on Heroku, I restored the structure and data from a local backup created using pg_dump.

I am unable to add new data to any table via Django admin. I get:

> null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint

when adding data for any model. What's going on with this database?

Comment: did you check the db for `None` values in `id`fields? Maybe some ids got deleted and since the maybe the `pk`, they are required. Another option would be to manually set an id attribute and set `blank=True` or `null=true`.

Comment: The operation in question is just a create in Django admin, it's not custom code. I'm just going to wipe the database and re-migrate and see if I run into the same issue.